# Why doesn't this SQL command work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot figure out why this sql query isn't working and why it doesn't filter by the keyword coming from URL.

Here is my code:

```
include("menujednoty.php");
$hostname="localhost";  
$username="kintrogorgo";  
$password="password";  
$keyword = $_GET['a.tovar'];
$db = "jednoty";  
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);  
foreach($dbh->query  ('SELECT a.tovar ,
( select sum(b.kusy) from jednotypredaj as b where b.tovar=a.tovar and b.co="prijem" ) as prijem_ks,
( select sum(c.kusy) from jednotypredaj as c where c.tovar=a.tovar and c.co="predaj" ) as predaj_ks, kod
FROM jednotypredaj WHERE
 (a.tovar LIKE '%$keyword%' ) as a GROUP BY a.tovar ORDER by a.tovar ASC') as $row)
 {     
     echo "<tr>"; 
     echo "<td>" . $row['tovar'] . "</td>";  
     echo "<td>" . $row['prijem_ks']. "</td>";  //Tu by mali bit predane kusy
     echo "<td>" . $row['predaj_ks'] . "</td>"; 
     echo "<td>" . $row['kod'] . "</td>";  

     echo "<td>" . ($row['predaj_ks']-$row['prijem_ks'] . "</td>");
     echo "<td>" . (100/$row['prijem_ks']*$row['predaj_ks']  . "</td>");
     echo '<td><a href="3edit.php?tovar=' . $row['tovar'] . '">Zobraziť</a></td>';
     //echo '<td><a href="3test.php?tovar=' . $row['tovar'] . '">In Development</a></td>';
     //echo '<td><a href="3testtest.php?tovar=' . $row['tovar'] . '">In Development 2</a></td>';
```

Comment: what does doesn't work mean? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add `php` to the tags. Please use parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection `(a.tovar LIKE :keyword' )`

Comment: Consider using `PDO::prepare()` and `PDOStatement::execute()` to make it easier to separate the SQL from the HTML

Comment: when i put there (a.tovar LIKE :keyword' ) it is not working.It wrote me this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '', ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /volume1/web/lukas/orange/33.php on line 42

Comment: That's a PHP error because you add single quotes inside string literal (already wrapped in singles). MySQL will then throw an error for the table alias, `a`, after `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are breaking the SQL syntax, rewrite as a prepared statement to make it easier:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT a.tovar ,
    ( select sum(b.kusy) from jednotypredaj as b 
      where b.tovar=a.tovar and b.co=:received ) as prijem_ks,
    ( select sum(c.kusy) from jednotypredaj as c
       where c.tovar=a.tovar and c.co=:paid ) as predaj_ks, kod
    FROM jednotypredaj WHERE
    (a.tovar LIKE :keyword ) as a 
    GROUP BY a.tovar ORDER by a.tovar ASC');

$stmt->execute(array('received' => 'prijem','paid' => 'predaj','keyword' => $keyword));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
  echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row['tovar'] . "</td>";  
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Reconsider your SQL statement as you can either run correlated subqueries or conditional aggregates. Also, you table alias, `a`, was incorrectly positioned after `WHERE` clause:

Correlated subqueries *(retains unit level records with `kod` column)*

```
SELECT a.tovar, 
      (select sum(b.kusy) from jednotypredaj as b 
       where b.tovar=a.tovar and b.co='prijem') as prijem_ks, 
      (select sum(c.kusy) from jednotypredaj as c 
       where c.tovar=a.tovar and c.co='predaj') as predaj_ks, 
       a.kod 
FROM jednotypredaj as a
WHERE (a.tovar LIKE '%$keyword%') 
ORDER by a.tovar ASC
```

Conditional aggregates *(group by aggregate records w/o `kod` unless added as a group)*

```
SELECT a.tovar, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN a.co='prijem' THEN a.kusy ELSE NULL END) as prijem_ks, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN a.co='predaj' THEN a.kusy ELSE NULL END) as predaj_ks
FROM jednotypredaj as a
WHERE (a.tovar LIKE '%$keyword%')
GROUP BY a.tovar
ORDER by a.tovar ASC
```

MySQL may allow `kod` in `SELECT` clause and not in `GROUP BY` clause of aggregate query if your instance has the [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) setting turned off but is not recommended and not ANSI-SQL compliant.

And as mentioned parameterize these queries in PHP script, binding string literals, that helps avoid quote handling and SQL injection.

Comment: I do not know how to really use any one of code which you wrote me. always i am getting error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'prijem' (T_STRING)

Comment: It must be due to your quotes. If you are not parameterizing, use double quotes around entire SQL statement and then single quotes around the literals: *'prijem'*, *'predaj'*, *'%$keyword%'*

Comment: Great! If answer helped, please accept to confirm resolution.

Comment: I am here new where i can do it?

Comment: See noticeable [checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to left of question.